# LINQ to SQL is creating wrong relations

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on small shopping cart project, and I'm using asp.net mvc 4 with SQL Server 2008, and development environment is Visual Studio 2013.

I have created database and I will give example:

I have one table called `TransactionLines` where I store purchased products, now I have relation to table `Products`, so relation in SQL Server Management Studio is OK

```
TransactionLines:ProductID -> Products:ProductID
```

but when I create `.dbml` file in VS relation is from `TransactionLines:TransactionLineID -> Products:ProductID`.

Does anyone know what is the problem with it?

Screen shot from SQL Server Management Studio

[image]

Screen shot from VS Server Explorer

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can manually correct or check associations

Comment: Yes, I know that I can manually correct, but I'm constantly changing things and I like to delete all objects and drag them again in order to avoid fixing it all the time, cause I have manually fixed it today 10 times.

Comment: Maybe it's bizarrely cached somehow if your first version of the DBML didn't contain the new FK. If you haven't already, try to delete the entire DBML, delete server connection, make new connection and new DBML and see if it resolves. If not then you may want to post actual DB schema (with create script) in case something in there is causing this behavior.

Comment: I have deleted it, remove it, disconnect it, restart sql server nothing worked, and then I restarted my PC and it's working like a charm.

Comment: Wow, can't explain that one - I think it was probably ghosts, or aliens. Glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: I always thought that VS is keeping me sane, but now it's making me insane, probably cause this 2013 was quick product :)

Answer (score 0):

It must be bug with Visual Studio 2013, as I had this problem as well and a system reboot fixed it.
It came back a few weeks later and as far as I can tell it happens when I change certain tables in the DBML I need to immediately reboot the system after save and it works.  I am still trying to figure out a better solution to UPDATING my DBML without requiring a system reboot.